# In Azure DevOps Server 2020 is it possible to prevent the Checkout task from having a different name each time?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

Please observe the following snapshot from the Build Analytics:

[image]

It shows essentially the same task - **Checkout**, but because the branch name is part of the task name we see it as different entries.

It is a problem if we want to analyze the performance of the checkout task.

This is true for both classic and YAML builds.

My question - is there a config option anywhere to stop the branch name from being part of the task name?  We do not care about the repo name, because it is constant, so it can be dropped too or it can be left - does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question - is there a config option anywhere to stop the branch name from being part of the task name?

AFAIK, I am afraid there is no such way to stop the branch name from being part of the task name by default.

For the classic pipeline, there is no such variable we could use to set the checkout task name.

For the YAML pipeline, we could add the displayName for the checkout to set the checkout task name:

```
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    displayName: CheckOut_MyTestName
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, this is good enough. We use YAML.